# Getting keys from nested dictionary without using for loops

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, list-comprehension

My Problem:
I have a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
my_dict = {
    'type_1' : {
        'id1' : some_item,
        'id2' : some_item_2,
    },
    'type_2' :{
        'id3' : some_item3,
        'id4' : some_item4,
    }
}
```

I don't intent to add more nesting in those sub_dicts, so I think this should be fairly easy.

Now I want to get all to get all inner keys (everything that starts with 'id') in one list,
so that i get `['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4]`

The easy way would be to use two for loops, but I want it to be as concise as humanly possible.

My initial approach looks like this:
`all_keys = [list(sub_dict.keys()) for sub_dict in my_dict.values()]` which outputs
`[['id1', 'id2'], ['id3', 'id4']]` which is halfway to where I want to get.
Adding an asterisk in front of `list(sub_dict(keys))` raises a syntax error:
"iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension"

Any idea how I get all 'id'-strings in one unnested list with max one additional line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to access to values of the dict then the keys of that value

```
new_dict=[id for i in my_dict.values() for id in i.keys()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to un-ravel the keys of the nested dictionaries, as below:

```
res = [key for d in my_dict.values() for key in d.keys() if isinstance(key, str) and key.startswith("id")]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4']
```

Additionally you need to check that the keys are actually strings (using [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)) and then check if they start with "id" (using [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)).

As an alternative use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
res = [key for key in chain.from_iterable(my_dict.values()) if isinstance(key, str) and key.startswith("id")]
print(res)
```

Also as suggested by @user2390182 you don't need to use .keys() on the nested dictionaries, just do:

```
res = [key for sub_dict in my_dict.values() for key in sub_dict if isinstance(key, str) and key.startswith("id")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You solution is OK and you can correct this with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) like below:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(sub_dict for sub_dict in my_dict.values()))
['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4']
```

By thanks @user2390182 shorted approach:

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(my_dict.values()))
# Or
>>> [*chain(*map(chain, my_dict.values()))]
['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4']
```

Comment: I wonder whether we could access such dictionaries (or yaml files organised as jsons) the way we access mongo databases. That would be useful.